# PHP $array[0] in $string for JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to use PHP to make a JSON file. Part of the code is as follow

```
$array = array("hello", "world");
$string='{"person": [
                     {
                      "name":'$array[0];',
                      "age":'$array[1];'
                     }
                    ]
          }';
```

The file created. However, $array[0] and $array[1] doesn't return the values "hello" and "world" but as $array[0] and $array[1]

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not concatenate right. Use the . to connect strings in php:

```
$array = array("hello", "world");
$string='{"person": [
                     {
                      "name":'.$array[0].',
                      "age":'.$array[1].'
                     }
                    ]
          }';
```

Comment: it does work. however (as others have stated here) you should consider using built-in functions to create JSON output

Comment: ok I will read more on this

Answer (score 1):

Consider using built-in PHP function such as [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: This should be a comment an not an answer.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear in the first place, I did use json_encode($string) and fwrite to create the file, problem is the variable doesn't return its value.

Answer (score 1):

There no need to make json your own. there is php function to do it as below

```
$data = array(
  "person"=>array(
     "name"=>"hello",
     "age"=>"world"
   )
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: I am very new to this, I learn it from tutorial I found somewhere on the net. Thanks for the guide, it is so much easier